# Clementine cannot open files: Can not find 'kioslave' executable

Tags: permissions, snap, clementine

I noticed that this is a Snap package. In the Discover tool, I enabled all permissions for it. But still it doesn't work.

The error:

```
Unable to create io-slave. Can not find 'kioslave' executable at '/snap/clementine/1024/usr/bin, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/libexec, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5'
```

This happens when I select "Open file" from the menu.

When I drag & drop some file to it, this did not work initially, but after enabling all permissions, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Then remove Snap version and install deb-version instead by

```
snap remove clementine

sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

Note: when versions [are](https://snapcraft.io/clementine) [equal](https://snapcraft.io/clementine), then deb-package is preferred way to install, IMO.

Comment: Why is this not the default, if this is the preferred way?